# All possible option for the registry key Product Name in windows?

Tags: windows, registry

I'm trying to build a list of all the option that are available (form windows 7 ad higher) in the following registry key:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductName

I couldn't find any documentation or any other question that will tell me what all the options are.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

My Windows 10 Professional machine has the value of "Windows 10 Pro" for ProductName key.

I am unable to find the full exhaustive list but here are some outputs I got:
Windows Server 2019 Evaluation
Windows Server 2019 Standard
Windows 10 Pro
Windows XP

Comment: Hi I'm looking for all the possibilities and not a specific one.